# How to add pictures to a javaFX 2.0 netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, javafx-2

Hello and thank you for your time. I am new to Netbeans and I am using the Netbeans 7.1 RC1 version of Netbeans. The problem I am running into is that I seem unable to add images to the project. I am designing a web app in JavaFX 2.0 and need a jpg picture for my background. I need to know how to add this picture to the Netbeans file system to be able to call it from my program. Any help is appreciated. Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is to put it directly into src folder, they you would be able to refer to it from your JavaFX application by next code:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image.png")));
```

Comment: Sergey do you ever go to chat? I would like to chat with you for a little while, I have some questions you might be able to answer with ease. I will be on chat all day today. See ya there.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image.png")));
```

it is showing error Image is an abstract class not be instantiated so how we can immplement it help

Comment: ^ You're probably importing Image from awt. Change your import for javafx.