# javafx deploying jar file

Tags: java, oracle, deployment, javafx

I am using netbeans to developed javafx application. But i can't deploy to single jar file (standalone). In Oracle's web site there is a [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#BCGIBBCI) but its complicated. And also i tried some others programs like launch4j, innosetup etc. Is there a video or picture tutorial for this? Is there a trick or easy way to do this.

note: in project folder there exist **sqlite** database, jdbc **libraries** and some **pictures**, not only java and fxml classes.

projectname-->db-->database.sqlite

projectname-->pic-->image.png

projectname-->lib-->jdbc-sqlite.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"in project folder there exist sqlite database, jdbc libraries and some pictures, not only java and fxml classes." - There's an issue!

- Put pictures in some java package and load them as a resources. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435518/how-to-add-pictures-to-a-javafx-2-0-netbeans-project?rq=1).
- You cannot pack sqlite db in `jar`. However, you can alter your application to create database on first start up (if database doesn't exist). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950482/creating-database-in-jdbc-sqlite).
- Necessary libraries should be packed in `jar` if you are using something like `Eclipse IDE's` to `Runnable JAR` wizard.